# Java Generics - raw type and parameterized type conversions

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I've been reading Java Generics Tutorials and few threads in Stackoverflow that deal with Generics, and still could not understand a specific case.
Here it is:

```
public class Box<T>
{
    private T t;

    public T getT ()
    {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT (T t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Box<Integer> intBox = new Box<Integer>();
        Box rawBox = intBox;
        rawBox.setT("NBA");
        System.out.println(rawBox.getT());
        System.out.println(intBox.getT());
        /*1*/ //System.out.println(intBox.getT().toString());
    }
}
```

Here's the deal,the first print I understand, that is,

```
 System.out.println(rawBox.getT());
```

prints NBA, because rawBox is of raw type of Box T and it "gives" us Objects.

What I don't get is the second print:

```
System.out.println(intBox.getT());
```

which prints NBA. 
intBox is of a generic type (in this case Box of Integers), which means its getter method should return a value of type T (which is Integer in this case), so what I understand is that the String object held there should be converted to Integer (because this is the argument type given to Box T) and a ClassCastException should be raised in runtime, but it doesn't happen, why is that?

By the way, comment number /*1*/ adds to the confusion, because if I were to uncomment it, it'll cause ClassCastException to be raised in ruuntime (String cannot be cast to Integer), I don't understand that

Thanks all  :)

Answer (score 2):

It's sometimes hard to guess where Java will insert checked casts.  In general, it'll only insert them where necessary.  The best way to understand the behavior you see is by checking the bytecode!

If we run `javap -c Box.class` (after compiling with `/*1*/` uncommented), we see:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
      ...
      20: invokevirtual #8                  // Method getT:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      23: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      26: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      29: aload_1
      30: invokevirtual #8                  // Method getT:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      33: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      36: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      39: aload_1
      40: invokevirtual #8                  // Method getT:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      43: checkcast     #10                 // class java/lang/Integer
      46: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/Integer.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      49: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      52: return
```

You can see here that the only time the JVM actually requires a cast to integer is at #43 (checkcast).  That's so that it can `invokevirtual Integer.toString()`.

The call to `println` (#33) does not require a cast because `println` takes an `Object`, not an `Integer` (perhaps you thought you were calling `println(int)`, but you're not).  So the JVM never needs to check that it's an integer, because it doesn't need to be.

If instead of calling `println(Object)`, you called a method that accepted an `Integer`, you should see a `ClassCastException` instead.

For example, this:

```
    ...
    print(intBox.getT());
}

private static void print(Integer integer) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Will perform a cast:

```
  26: aload_1
  27: invokevirtual #8                  // Method getT:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  30: checkcast     #10                 // class java/lang/Integer
  33: invokestatic  #11                 // Method print:(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
```

Comment: first of, great answer,
 I understood your take on the println method that accepts arguments of   type Object.
This still doesn't explain why without invoking the println method, the following statement:
intBox.getT();  doesn't raise the ClassCastException:String cannot be cast to Integer.
That statement compiles and runs fine.
If intBox is a parameterized type (Integer), its getter method should return Integer,  and the conversion from String to Integer
should result in the exception being raised from within the getter method itself, and  that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Michael1: It will always be up to the *caller* of the generic method to enforce the return type of the cast.  Recall there is not a separate `.class` file generated for each instantiated type.  In other words, there would be no place in `Box.class` to add a cast to `Integer`, because it needs to work for all types.  It only enforces the *erasure* of the parameter (in this case the erasure is `Object`).  Then the caller is required to do the cast if/when it becomes necessary.

Comment: From [JLS 15.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.5): *there are situations where the statically known type may not be accurate at run time. Such situations can arise in a program that gives rise to compile-time unchecked warnings. Such warnings are given in response to operations that cannot be statically guaranteed to be safe, and **cannot immediately be subjected to dynamic checking because they involve non-reifiable types**. As a result, **dynamic checks later in the course of program execution may (...) result in run-time type errors**.*

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure is the reason. At runtime, all Box instances are equal, they all contain references. Generics only benefit you, the programmer, to convey type information and keep your program well typed.

Answer (score 0):

This is why the compiler warns you against using non-generic class references. During runtime, it has no ability to know what type intbox is, because it generics are not saved in bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the type erasure.
As from article [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

> During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type
> parameters and replaces each with its **first bound** if the type
> parameter is bounded, or **Object** if the type parameter is unbounded.
>
> Consider the following generic class that represents a node in a
> singly linked list:
>
> ```
> public class Node<T> {
>
>     private T data;
>     private Node<T> next;
>
>     public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
>         this.data = data;
>         this.next = next;
>     }
>
>     public T getData() { return data; }
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Because the type parameter T is unbounded, the Java compiler replaces
> it with **Object**:
>
> ```
> public class Node {
>
>     private Object data;
>     private Node next;
>
>     public Node(Object data, Node next) {
>         this.data = data;
>         this.next = next;
>     }
>
>     public Object getData() { return data; }
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Note that `Box<Integer>` is unbounded.

Now you passed the compile time type safety check due to raw type

```
rawBox.setT("NBA");
```

which is also assigning to intBox.

Your declaration of getT():

```
public T getT ()
    {
        return t;
    }
```

becomes

```
public Object getT ()
        {
            return t;
        }
```

So you are returning an **Object**. Therefore

```
System.out.println(intBox.getT());
```

prints the string NBA as string is also an Object.

But in statement:

```
System.out.println(intBox.getT().toString());
```

you are calling method toString() on intBox.getT() so somewhere at compile time it is checking return type of intBox.getT() as Integer and treating intBox.getT().toString() as Integer_object.toString() at run time.

so when at run time you pass string to it ClassCastException came.